# Get the Date in yyyy-MM-dd format c#

Tags: c#

I am getting the date in DateTime format.
e.g. 3/26/2015 12:00:00 AM
I want to to convert it into Date Time (YYYY-MM-DD).

My output should be in DateTime :

```
DateTime obj = 2015-03-26
```

I tried,

```
string value = "11/12/2009";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true); 
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

But for no avail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to be under the impression that a `DateTime` *has* a format. It doesn't - no more than an `int` is neither decimal, nor hex, nor binary - but could be converted to any of those textual representations.

It sounds like you should just use `DateTime.Parse` for your incoming data (unless you know the *exact* format to expect, in which case specify that), keep the result as a `DateTime` for as long as you can, and then use `ToString` with a custom format string to format it when you need to. (Don't convert it into text until you *do* need to though... Avoid conversions as much as you can, as each one is a potential source of errors.)

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(value, culture);
...
// Lots of other code
...
string isoDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: to help with the custom format in toStrings, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you always receive date in format `3/26/2015 12:00:00 AM`, then you can use

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("3/26/2015 12:00:00 AM", 
                                  "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then do

```
String mydateFormat = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", 
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `mm` means minutes, not months... and `MM/dd/yyyy` isn't the format the OP wants.

Comment: Now "MM" won't match "3" :) It's also not clear whether this is *always* the format the OP will receive, or whether it's just known to be "a valid date and time for a specified culture" (where the culture could vary on each call).

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal :I have to assign that value to a property which is of DateTime type. But the final result(mydateFormat) from your answer is of string type.
Please suggest